# iOS Google Map API ERROR

Tags: ios, google-maps

hi i have some problem when i use google maps on ios.
First, I installed cocoa pods and set the google api.
(and insert api key into the AppDelegate.swift file)

But this error happened :(
->
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

what is the problem

here is the code

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class LocationAddVC: UIViewController{

//Take a Google Map Object.
// Don't make outlet from Storyboard,
// Break the outlet of GMSMapView if you made an outlet

var mapView:GMSMapView?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200), camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 51.050657, longitude: 10.649514, zoom: 5.5))

    //so the mapView is of width 200, height 200 and its center is same as center of the self.view
    mapView?.center = self.view.center

    self.view.addSubview(mapView!)

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works perfectly. I removed the api-key or used wrong key the same error happened.

I think a few things you must check:

1. Check if the api-key is initialized at the right place. (refer my code)
2. Check whether the api-key is correct or not.
3. Check whether you enabled Map SDK for iOS app on google developer account.
4. Finally, check there are no restrictions on the iOS bundle identifier for the api-key.

Here is my working code:

**AppDelegate:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("api-key")

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView:GMSMapView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Take a Google Map Object.
        // Don't make outlet from Storyboard,
        // Break the outlet of GMSMapView if you made an outlet

            mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200), camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 51.050657, longitude: 10.649514, zoom: 5.5))

            //so the mapView is of width 200, height 200 and its center is same as center of the self.view
            mapView?.center = self.view.center

            self.view.addSubview(mapView!)

        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) it was my mistake. i didn't enable api key  thank you very much